# Extended Toolkit's NumericUpDown in hex output

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I am using the Extended Toolkit for WPF.

The NumericUpDown control is capable of inputting hex values, but I cannot see a method/property for showing values in hex format.

There is a FormatString, but this contains thinks like currency, percentage, not hex format.

The code in WPF I have now is:

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Value}" 
     ParsingNumberStyle="HexNumber" FormatString="%X" Margin="4" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

```
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown ParsingNumberStyle="HexNumber" 
                        FormatString="X" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Haven't tried yet but it looks exactly what I need! Looks like the documentation at http://elegantcode.com/2010/11/07/extended-wpf-toolkitrelease-1-2-0/ is incomplete regarding the formatting.